# TextArea without vertical Scrollbar as long as numbers of visible rows are not used

Tags: javascript, html, css, xhtml

I've a TextArea with 3 rows.

Problem: Firefox does not show the vertical scrollbar until the user has used more than 3 rows but Internet Explorer 8 always show the scrollbar.

I need Firefox's behaviour in Internet Explorer 8.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`<textarea style="overflow:auto" />`

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I've tried this already but it's not working.

Answer (score 0):

Might be firxfox's rendering issue.

You might want to specify the height as well, perhaps give this a try:

```
yourtextarea.yourclass
{
  overflow: auto;
  height: 30;
}
```